# handling arguments in Lua function with variable number of arguments

Tags: lua, lua-table

I was trying to write a function with a variable number of arguments which do something for all its number entries. so I came up with something like this:

```lua
function luaFunc (...)
   for i,v in ipairs{...} do
      if type(v)=='number' then
         --do something
      end
   end
end
```

but when i run this, it stops right on first non-number argument. whats the problem?

Comment: It stops at the first nil argument not at the first non-number argument.

Comment: thats right, thank you lhf.

Comment: if you read the docs for ipairs, it specifically tells you that it does this. i think what you are looking for here is the `pairs` function, which iterates all keys in a table (not necessarily in order).

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, thank you. that's simply the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local function luaFunc (...)
   for i = 1, select('#',...) do
      local v = select(i,...)
      if type(v)=='number' then
         --do something
         print(v)
      end
   end
end
luaFunc (1,'a',nil,2)     ]

-- Output
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
function luaFunc (...)
   local t=table.pack(...)
   for i=1,t.n do
      local v=t[i]
      if type(v)=='number' then
         print(i,v)
      end
   end
end

luaFunc(10,20,"hello",40,nil,60,print,99)
```

Comment: also useful. thank you. btw why should the iteration with ipairs not work? the element has a key and has a value which is nil ..

Comment: @VahidM, `ipairs` uses the `#` operator on the table to determine how many elements it has but `#` is not useful for tables with holes (nil entries).

Comment: I've just tested # operator for a table with nil entries and it worked fine. It must be something else. thank you anyway.

Comment: @VahidM, try `N=100; t={}; for i=1,N do t[i]=i end; t[64]=nil; print(#t)`.